# Can theano work on mapreduce or on spark?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, apache-spark

I am not sure whether the Theano library can be used to write parallelized code in map reduce or in spark. Any expert opinion is welcome. A discussion was on at:
[Theano-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/theano-dev/theano$20spark/theano-dev/QDN94MW3LkE/k817aa75xZoJ)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think theano have spark support yet, however there are at least 2 deep learning libraries that are good with that. The first one is [mxnet](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet), they have support for spark, R, python and C++. Another option is [deeplearning4j](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j), made in Java with direct access to Spark.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any support for Map-Reduce or Spark for theano but if you want to run it in a distributed setting you can refer to [this technical report](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08325.) on using theano with MPI.

PS : Authors of the above mentioned report have released the code for the same. You can find it [here](https://github.com/uoguelph-mlrg/Theano-MPI).